# Prevent msg concatenation with asyncio sockets

Tags: python, sockets

I am using the standard asyncio socket client boiler plate below:

```
import asyncio

async def repetitive_client_request(message, loop):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8888, loop=loop)
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        writer.write(message.encode())
        await writer.drain()

        data = await reader.read(100)
        print('Received: {}'.format(data.decode()))

        print('Close the socket')
        writer.close()

message = 'hi'
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(repetitive_client_request(message, loop))
loop.close()
```

97% of the time everything works fine, but occasionally successive requests are being concatenated into for example `'hihihihi'`. Somebody suggested this behaviour is not entirely uncommon with TCP. How can I change the above to UDP, and should this expect to solve the issue?

Edit: Just found this in docs: `Changed in version 3.6: The socket option TCP_NODELAY is now set by default.`  So it appears its not Nagle responsible for this message concatenation.

Comment: TCP can do that anyway, any time it likes. Disabling the Nagle algorithm isn't a certain cure. You need to implement messages at your application protocol level.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second part please, i.e. how can I implement things differently to prevent message concatenation?

Comment: See my answer for a simple example of implementing messages at the protocol level.

Answer (score 1):

> Somebody suggested this behaviour is not entirely uncommon with TCP. How can I change the above to UDP

Before switching the whole code to UDP, there is another option - you can make your protocol self-delimiting, so that the individual messages cannot get merged by the underlying transport.

For example, you can send your data using:

```
writer.write(struct.pack('<L', len(data)))
writer.write(data)
```

When reading, use:

```
size, = struct.unpack('<L', await reader.readexactly(4))
data = await reader.readexactly(size)
```

This is simple to implement, retains the comfort of working with TCP, and prevents concatenation.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is incorrect. Making one's protocol be delimited is nice, but does not affect whether TCP will concatenate write()s or not.

Comment: @studog The answer is fine. When you read using a self-delimited or framed protocol, it doesn't matter whether TCP concatenates the writes, you read them correctly regardless of how many individual OS-level reads you receive them in. (This is accomplished by `readexactly`.)

Comment: @studog I think I now see the misunderstanding. This answer was written for a very specific audience: people who try to write two things to a TCP socket, and then are surprised that on the reading side they don't receive them in two reads of the same sizes. For those people UDP (or custom protocol built over it) is overkill, they just need to use a proper protocol over TCP, and TCP will serve them nicely.

Comment: @studog So when the answers says that messages "cannot get merged", it means to say that merging them will have no observable effect. Of course, if you count timing, then you're totally right, but then we're in expert territory. I didn't downvote your comment, and I don't think it's even possible to do so? A comment can be flagged for rudeness and such, but I didn't do that - I welcome healthy disagreement and discussion, and have read your comments in that spirit.